# Get value in bit size

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

In SQL Server & Oracle, is it possible to get the bit size of the value?

I know an int takes up 4 bytes of storage and a nvarchar(n) stores 2 times n bytes + 2 bytes, but I'm only interested in the actual value.

If I for instance want to check an entire row with different data types, is it possible to get the bit size of each actual value?

Can the SQL Server function DATALENGTH() be applied in a universal way not depending on the data type?

Comment: I don't think there is one without adding  them up. You could use sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats if it'll suffice, or do something like: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25532/95107

Comment: In SQL Server, you can't say `DATALENGTH(*)`, but you can say `DATALENGTH(col1)+DATALENGTH(col2)+...` you can build that dynamically but to measure the active, current size of each row, you can't do so without the command explicitly mentioning each column (you can probably skip fixed-width columns, though, as they will be the same on every non-null row).

Comment: (Also you should probably post a different question for each RDBMS. You're unlikely to get a correct answer who knows the "best" solution for both platforms.)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, the `DUMP` command's output will include the length (in bytes) of an actual value.  You can then use string functions to pull the length out of the output.  E.g.,

```
select dump(3.141592), 
       regexp_substr(dump(3.141592),'Len=([0-9]+)',1,1,'i',1) byte_length
from dual
```

> ```
> +-----------------------------+-------------+
> |       DUMP(3.141592)        | BYTE_LENGTH |
> +-----------------------------+-------------+
> | Typ=2 Len=5: 193,4,15,16,93 |           5 |
> +-----------------------------+-------------+
> ```

You would need to do this for each column and add them up.

Also, be aware that Oracle computes (or estimates) the average row length of data in a table when it computes (or estimates) the statistics on that table.  The results go in `DBA_TABLES.AVG_ROW_LEN`.